Changing the display order of products in WooCommerce site based on price
How can I display WooCommerce products in the following order on category pages?

Available products with prices higher than 0
next

Products available with or without price
And then

Products out of stock


ill tried this code but I think some parts of the code have problems, some parts may need to be deleted and some parts need to be changed.

add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_product_order', 100);

function custom_product_order($query) {
    add_filter('posts_clauses', 'custom_product_order_clauses', 100, 2);
    return $query;
}

function custom_product_order_clauses($clauses, $query) {
    global $wpdb;

    $pos = strpos($clauses['join'], 'wc_product_meta_lookup wc_product_meta_lookup');
    if ($pos === false) {
        $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}wc_product_meta_lookup wc_product_meta_lookup ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id ";
    }

    $has_price = " IF(wc_product_meta_lookup.min_price > 0, 0, 1) ASC, ";
    $stock_status = " FIELD(wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_status, 'instock' , 'outofstock') ASC, ";

    $clauses['orderby'] =  $has_price . $stock_status . $clauses['orderby'];

    return $clauses;
}


